# ошибка при вызове функции int64_t

Tags: c, visual-studio

Имеется простой код:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

int64_t func(int base);
int main()
{
    int k = 2;
    int64_t res;
    res = func(k);
    printf("Press any key...");
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
int64_t func(int base)
{
    int64_t z = 0;
    return z;
}
```

Он компилируется, но если запускать на исполнение (VS2012) и поставить breakpoint на `printf`, чтобы посмотреть, чему равно значение `res`, выпадает окно:

> нет доступных исходных файлов. в текущем потоке в данный момент не
>   выполняется код, или не удалось получить стек вызова.

Не могу понять, что VS не нравится.

**P.S.**

Оптимизация кода в свойствах проекта отключена.

Comment: Вы его компилировали с отключенной оптимизацией? просто ощущение, что оптимизатор постарался и выкинул все ненужное.

Comment: @Harry, ды вроде в режиме Debug всё строится.

Comment: @Setplus, а если в другие места ставить breakpoint (`getchar`, `return` или в самой `func`)?

Comment: @Ternvein, вот если в return поставить, то программа выведет содержимое printf. на getchar вылетает

Comment: А почему нет очистки вывода после ввода числа? Получается, что сразу после ввода прога завершается.

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch, поясните подробнее, пожалуйста.

Comment: Когда пишешь число и нажимаешь ENTER число считывается, а символ новой строки возвращается в поток ввода. Если следующая операция - взять из потока символ, то он возьмет этот самый символ новой строки

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch, а где здесь "*ввод числа*"?

Comment: Ах да, верно - ошибся.

Comment: В **VS** есть `__int64` вместо `int64_t`

Comment: @entithat, проблема, как оказалось, не в типах.

Answer (score 0):

Для моей ситуации помогло следующее:

Идём в **свойства проекта/свойства конфигурации/отладка**.

В графе **Тип отладчика** вместо **Авто** поставил **Смешанный код**.

Если что, у меня Visual Studio 2012 Professional.